# Is there a way to translate dynamic content used as interpolation - Internationalization i18n?

Tags: angular, internationalization

I'am using the i18n internationalization for an application and I do have in some components a dynamic messages and text which is being dynamically embedded in the HTML via `interpolation`.

e.g. here I would like to provide a translation for the variable **`{{errorMessage}}`**

```
....
err => {
   this.errorMessage = 'Please check your credentials...!';
}
....
```

Is there a way to use/add the translation for this kind of content in the translation files: **`messages.es.xlf`** and **`messages.fr.xlf`**?

I have been searching and it seems to not be available or at least possible in the actual status/stage of i18n development... [i18n: Able to use translation strings outside a template](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11405)

Comment: This is what third-party i18n extensions are for.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Issue solved. The translation for dynamic content is being added in `message.*.xlf` files straightforward when running: `ng xi18n`. It adds following for dynamic text `interpolation` e.g. `<source><x id="INTERPOLATION" equiv-text="{{ myDynamicText }}"/></source>`